# Как искать конкретную зависимость в кастомном репозитории sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

Имею следующий `build.sbt` в который добавил кастомный репозиторий:

```
name := "CryptoToolsTest"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.6"

resolvers += "3rd party" at "http://some.custom.uri.ru:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "ru.group" % "artifact_1" % "1.0",
  "org.group" % "artifact_2" % "1.0"
)
```

С такой конфигурацией, кастомный репозиторий `3rd party` доступен для поиска всех зависимостей.
Как сделать так, чтоб `SBT` искал в кастомном репозитории, например, зависимость `artifact_2` и только ее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое близкое, что нашел:

```
name := "CryptoToolsTest"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "ru.group" % "artifact_1" % "1.0",
  "org.group" % "artifact_2" % "1.0"
    from "http://some.custom.uri.ru:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/org/group/artifact_2/1.0/artifact_2-1.0.jar"
)
```

Не совсем то, что хотел, так как нужно указывать путь до конкретного `jar`, а не до репозитория.

Comment: Насколько я знаю это единственный способ ограничить поиск одной конкретной зависимости. Если вы публикуете этот артифакт в этот репозиторий, то вы можете опубликовать его с другим классификатором или версией. Тогда можно добавить репозиторий как обычно, но зависеть от этой специально версии.

Comment: У меня кастомный репозиторий - чужой. И артефакт в нем тоже не мой.